# How to Use ctrl+c in shell script?

Tags: c, linux, shell, exit, ctrl

I want to create a script and want to use cat > file name but i don't know how to use ctrl+c to exit cat redirection. How to write shell script using cat redirection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant Ctrl + Z and end-of-file. You can use it like this in a shell script:

```
cat > ./myfile << EOF
hello world
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are redirecting from cat.

If you are redirecting from standard input (i.e., what you type in):

`cat - > filename`

Then to stop capturing the keyboard you have to enter Ctrl+D to signal the end of the stream. Then the next line in your script will execute.

If you are redirecting from one or more files like this:

`cat file1 file2 file3 > allfiles`

Then there is nothing you have to do to stop the redirection. cat will concatenate (hence the name cat) all files sequentially into "allfiles". If they are big it will take a while but that's not cat's fault, it's the time it takes the OS to do the I/O.